# Install new payment method for Store

Tags: expresso-store

I just downloaded the Sisow (https://github.com/fruitcakestudio/omnipay-sisow) gateway for Store and copied all the files to the /store/vendor/omnipay/sisow dir.

But unfortunately the Sisow Gateway is not showing in the Store CP.

How do i add more custom gateways to the omnipay lib?

Answer (score 0):

Additional gateways need to be included into Store via an extension so you would need to create an ExpressionEngine Extension. Store has a sample extension of what the gateway should like [here](https://github.com/expressodev/store_check) with the proper folder structure and files needed to register an additional gateway.

You will need rename the ext.store_check.php file to match the namespace of the sisow gateway. Once you have done that you will need to add the folder to your third_party folder and enable the extension in the Add-ons > Extensions age of EE and configure it however needed before you can use it on the site.